# Is it possible to change the configuration of OVS switch in Mininet topology from ODL controller?

Tags: sdn, mininet, opendaylight

I am a newbie to SDN domain. I implemented my custom Mininet topology with multiple remote ODL controllers.

I am now testing to change the pre-configuration of OVS switch (i.e., controller ip address to another ip address of controller) in Mininet from ODL controller.

Is it possible to change the preconfigured mapping between switch and controller in run time?

If it is possible, I would like to know the steps to follow.

Answer (score 1):

You can either try to use server name instead of IP address, or you can put a tcp proxy between your switch and the controller.

Very simple example might be a use of netcat to forward traffic to the remote controller:

```
./netcat -L ${controller_ip_address}:${controller_openflow_port} -p ${local_port}
```

and let your mininet connect to netcat, which will forward the request to the remote controller

```
sudo mn --controller=remote,ip=127.0.0.1,port=${local_port}
```